# IIS7 URL Rewrite ignore rules in sub application

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have MyWebSite and MyApp as shown below:

```
MyWebSite
   web.config

   MyApp
      web.config
      Pages
         page.aspx
```

I want the next URL will work:
www.mywebsite.com/oldpage.aspx

1. MyWebSite\web.config add to the URL 'MyApp': www.mywebsite.com/**MyApp**/page.aspx
2. MyApp\web.config add to the URL 'Pages': www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/**Pages**/page.aspx

I want to separate this logic in two rules because I want each rule will responsible for its part. MyWebSite should decide which application is default, if not specified, and it should not know anything about 'Pages' in MyApp.

The problem, that the rule in MyApp is not called.

The question: do I do something wrong? Is this is limitation that I can't perform rewrites in separate config files?

P.S. MyWebSite and MyApp running under the same app pool.

---

MyWebSite web.config:

```
<rule name="Add 'MyWebSite' for ASPX pages">
    <match url="^([^/]+\.aspx)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="MyApp/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

MyApp web.config

```
<rule name="Add 'Pages'">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
         <add input="{URL}" pattern="Pages" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Pages/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant part of the web.config files? (the part where the rules are defined)

Comment: Can you try to use the [failed request tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and post the result here?

Comment: I used this tool. logs showing only rules from the MyWebSite web.config, nothing about MyApp. But other rules in the MyApp web.config do work well.

Comment: Can you, as a test, change `type="Rewrite"` to `type="Redirect"` in `MyWebSite web.config`

Comment: Redirect works. The problem only with Rewrite. Looks the URL rewrite module doesn't support such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do seems possible reading the following blog post: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules

However, the only way I succeeded in getting it to work was using a dirty trick. I am not sure it would be recommended in a production environment but in case you want to go with this solution:

MyWebSite `web.config`:

```
<rule name="Add 'MyWebSite' for ASPX pages">
    <match url="^([^/]+\.aspx)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I just changed the `Rewrite` destination to `url="http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/{R:1}"` (I have [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) up and running as well).